# How can I play hotstar videos on my Ubuntu16.04?

Tags: firefox

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC. I'm having problems playing hotstar videos on firefox. I installed flashplayer using:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-in
```

But it didn't help.

Comment: please help asap

Answer (score 0):

Hotstar website is not compatible with Linux/ Ubuntu OS.
 [image]

Comment: Could you please post messages, text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanx..Will improve next my answers.